# Numpy: getting a list of combinations of ratios such that they all add to 1

Tags: python, numpy, combinations, fractions

Suppose I have three different colors of paint and I want to test what happens when I mix them in various ratios. How do I get a list of those ratios?

I can do it with nested for-loops like this:

```
for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 6):
    for j in np.linspace(0, 1, 6):
        for k in np.linspace(0, 1, 6):
            if np.isclose(i+j+k, 1.0): ## catch floating point errors
                print(i, j, k)
```

This outputs the following:

```
0.0 0.0 1.0
0.0 0.2 0.8
0.0 0.4 0.6
0.0 0.6 0.4
0.0 0.8 0.2
0.0 1.0 0.0
0.2 0.0 0.8
0.2 0.2 0.6
0.2 0.4 0.4
0.2 0.6 0.2
0.2 0.8 0.0
0.4 0.0 0.6
0.4 0.2 0.4
0.4 0.4 0.2
0.4 0.6 0.0
0.6 0.0 0.4
0.6 0.2 0.2
0.6 0.4 0.0
0.8 0.0 0.2
0.8 0.2 0.0
1.0 0.0 0.0
```

Each line has three numbers and they all add up to one, and I have every possible combination for my specified degree of resolution. It works, but it's an awkward construction, and it requires a new loop for every new color of paint I add. If I wanted to mix 10 types of paint, I'd need 10 loops!

Is there a more elegant/pythonic way of doing this? A built-in numpy function maybe?

(Also I found it hard to summarise the question in the title, can anyone think of a better concise way of describing the problem?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` for this; effectively this is combinations with replacement. You can construct a list comprehension which filters for sum equal to 1.

```
from itertools import product

res = np.array([i for i in product(np.linspace(0, 1, 6), repeat=3) if sum(i) == 1])

# array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ],
#        [ 0. ,  0.2,  0.8],
#        [ 0. ,  0.4,  0.6],
#        [ 0. ,  0.6,  0.4],
#        [ 0. ,  0.8,  0.2],
#        [ 0. ,  1. ,  0. ],
#        [ 0.2,  0. ,  0.8],
#        [ 0.2,  0.2,  0.6],
#        [ 0.2,  0.4,  0.4],
#        [ 0.2,  0.6,  0.2],
#        [ 0.2,  0.8,  0. ],
#        [ 0.4,  0. ,  0.6],
#        [ 0.4,  0.2,  0.4],
#        [ 0.4,  0.4,  0.2],
#        [ 0.4,  0.6,  0. ],
#        [ 0.6,  0. ,  0.4],
#        [ 0.6,  0.2,  0.2],
#        [ 0.6,  0.4,  0. ],
#        [ 0.8,  0. ,  0.2],
#        [ 0.8,  0.2,  0. ],
#        [ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```